# iterating over array of objects in Handlebars not working

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

So I'm trying to iterate over an array that is being returned by a server as a json object. I'm already doing this once and it works just fine, but this other one here does not seem to work.

So the handlebars code looks like this

```
  <script id="messageTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each response.data}}
<div class="message">
  {{#messages}}
  <h4>{{this.from}}</h4>
  <b>{{this.datetime}}</b>
  <p>{{this.body}}</p>
  {{/messages}}
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

and the json object that I'm try to iterate over like this

```
 {
 "data": {
"id": 32607158,
"with_account": "user1",
"with_account_id": 8483786,
"last_message_preview": "XD",
"message_count": 289,
"messages": [{
  "id": 153359194,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711004
}, {
  "id": 153359270,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711023
}, {
  "id": 153359330,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711044
}, {
  "id": 153359334,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711048
}, {
  "id": 153359386,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711057
}, {
  "id": 153359430,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711065
}, {
  "id": 153359474,
  "from": "user1",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711078
}, {
  "id": 153359522,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 20094939,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711090
}, {
  "id": 153359638,
  "from": "user2",
  "account_id": 20094939,
  "sender_id": 8483786,
  "body": "*hugs*",
  "conversation_id": 32607158,
  "datetime": 1439711106
}],
"done": false,
"page": 2,
"datetime": 1439711387
},
"success": true,
"status": 200
}
```

Does anybody know why it's not working? Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `each` is in the wrong place. `data` is a single object so you don't need to iterate over that. You can use a `with` statement for `data`

```
                {{#with response.data}}
                <div class="message">
                    {{#each messages}}
                    <h4>{{this.from}}</h4>
                    <b>{{this.datetime}}</b>
                    <p>{{this.body}}</p>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
                {{/with}}
```

If you are compiling your template with the response object then the `with` would become

```
{{#with data}}
```